# Does the Hom-functor $H( _, A)$ take limits to colimits?

Tags: category-theory

Let *Ab* be the category of abelian groups, and $A$ a finitely generated abelian group. One can deduce the two Hom-functors $Hom(A,\:\_ \;): Ab \to Ab$ and $Hom(\:\_ \;,A): Ab^{op} \to Ab$, both of which are covariant.  My question is: Do both functors preserve colimits ?

I believe it is true for the first case, however, all my attempts to prove it for the second case fail. Can anybody give me a clue ?

Comment: Well, if your attempts to prove it fail, maybe you should look for a counterexample.

Comment: Taking into account what you said, one should look at the directed system $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z^3 \dots$, where each map is the obvious inclusion. Its colimit is the direct sum $\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)}$. However, after applying the contravariant functor $Hom(\;_\;, \mathbb Z)$, one gets an inverse system $\mathbb Z \leftarrow \mathbb Z^2 \leftarrow \mathbb Z^3...$, whose limit is the direct PRODUCT $\mathbb Z^\mathbb N$. This is not equal to $Hom(\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)},\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)}$, as the latter group is free abelian.

Comment: Is the statement true whenever the colimit is also finitely generated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by universal property of the limit and colimit both functors preserve limits.

Now let $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and define $B$ as the coequalizer
$$ B= \text{coeq}(0,\cdot 2)$$
where $0,\cdot 2\colon \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}.$ So in $Ab$, $B\cong \mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$ and in $Ab^{op}$, $\color{red}{B}\cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Now
$$ \text{Hom}(\color{red}{B},\mathbb{Z})= \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) \ne \text{coeq}(0,\cdot 2) $$
and
$$ \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},B) \cong B \ne \text{coeq}(\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\rightrightarrows \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) ) \cong 0. $$

This shows that both functors do not preserve colimits.

Comment: I think the OP is thinking to *filtered colimits*.

Comment: Oh ok. Then the first functor preserve those colimits and the second if the colimit is finitely generated.

Comment: Is there a good write-up for those kinds of properties ?

Comment: If you are interested in filtered colimits [this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compact+object) could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. So $A$ being *finitely presented* group is equivalent to the fact that the covariant functor $Hom(A, \; _ \;) : Ab \to Ab$ preserves *filtered* colimits, is this right ? But how do you prove that the *contravariant* functor $Hom( \; _ \; ,A): Ab \to Ab$ takes filtered, and finitely presented limits to colimits. I don't quite see this as a dual statement to the first one...

Comment: Yes it is right. [Here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/compact-objects/) it is the second example. The contravariant case it not dual since it is not true if the limit is not finitely generated as you pointed out in the comment to your question. In case it is finitely presented then you can pick a group in the filtered system which contains the generators and where relations are zero, but then it is isomorphic to the limit. (So the limit is already contained in the system and so there is not much happening in the limit, that's why it works in this case)